# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null! error

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I just learned how to use threads yesterday and I'm trying to encode some images using threads but I'll get this error 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null!
I tried doing this exact same thing without threads and it worked fine just kind of slowly, not because of the image io but because of the time it takes to encode images.
 the WinDef.HDC is a variable type I got from the JNA library. When I did try it without threads I could easily write out 1000 images (about 60mb).

```
//The thread class
public class imageEncoderThread extends Thread {

   HDC originalImage;
    BufferedImage image;


    public imageProcessThread (HDC rI) {
       originalImage = rI'
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //returns a buffered image
        image = process(rawImage);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File (filePath));
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }

}
```

---

---

```
 //full stack trace 
    Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null!
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.capture.SingleImageEncoderThread.run(Thread.java:33)
    Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null!
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.capture.SingleImageEncoderThread.run(Thread.java:33)
    Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null!
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)

 //and so on with the same exception
```

Comment: It seems image = JNAScreenShot.encodeRawWindow(rawImage, bounds); at this line image is null. Did you try printing System.out?

Comment: tried it just now it prints out null it seems that for some reason its not passing the object into the thread - on a side note when i checked the api for the WinDef.HDC it extends handle not sure if that has any to do with it?

Comment: I don't know what that method is, as soon as it is fixed, everything should work fine.

Comment: the code based off the JNA libary though when i tested it worked perfectly fine wihtout threads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost certainly the case that you cannot call:

```
image = JNAScreenShot.encodeRawWindow(rawImage, bounds);
```

from any thread other than the main ui thread. See:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/6398cda5-5393-4b16-b8dc-5bbf8902033f/ (specifically, I do not think HDCs are usable outside the main ui thread).

So, you'll need to create the screenshot first, then pass it to your thread to do the IO (that's probably the slow part, anyway).

Comment: yes this is just what iv been looking for all day, all my bugs seemed to be linked to the fact i took images(HDC) in a timer thread and tried to process them in another one

Comment: on a side note do you know ho the HDC thing works? I  just found out about it after donloawding the jna  libary. What im really curious about thous is where it stores information and how to  acess it

Comment: cant seem to really find  anything meaningful about the HDC class through google